# confusing workflow problem with conda envs

Tags: python, git, conda

I am developing a program and scheduling it to run every day using bash script. I have two branches of the program:

```
master
dev
```

I work in `dev` and merge with `master` whenever the work is complete. The scheduled tasks are intended to only run on `master` branch. I created a new conda env for just production stuff and I have a main conda env for development. However, even if I activate the production env in bash, it is still on the `dev` branch, which causes so much problems.

What is the proper structure that I should set up for this purpose?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure there is a "*proper structure*" for such a workflow. I'll share my thoughts, but this is more intended to inform a workflow design, rather than provide a specific recommendation.

#### Background

Conda environments manage shell state, whereas git branches manage things at a file-system level. Effectively, they are independent *by design*. One could manually couple them, but I would only do so with an abundance of caution and complete understanding of the risks involved. The main worry I have is that file-system states, such as managed by git, affect all shell sessions, so including state mutations (e.g., automated branch switching) in the Conda environments will affect all environments working in a given path.

#### Coupling Conda and Git

With that in mind, Conda environments will execute arbitrary shell scripts placed in `<env_dir>/etc/conda/(de|)activate.d/`. So, theoretically, one could add a script in the `activate.d` folder to ensure that the git repository has the `main` branch checked out. You may also want to place a symmetric script in the `deactivate.d` folder to restore the previously active branch.

An anticipatable situation to consider is what happens when the script cannot switch branches due to unstaged changes. Should it simply fail? Should it stash, log, and continue? Something else?

#### Two Copy Configuration

Personally, I would probably keep two copies of the git repository around at separate locations: one that has `dev` checked out and that always has `main` checked out. That way, one can continue to work on one branch while the execution branch always stays on `main`. Then I would use `activate.d` script to ensure that the `main` syncs with upstream every time prior to execution.